# Create new multidimensional array based on this existing array objec

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I'm stuck to construct a new multidimensional array based on this existing array object

```
acl:[
{
   view:true, 
   update:true, 
   remove:true, 
   userId:1, 
   username:"Mike"
},
{
   view:true, 
   update:true, 
   remove:false, 
   userId:2, 
   username:"Joe"
},
{
   view:true, 
   update:false, 
   remove:false, 
   userId:3, 
   username:"Lim"
}
]
```

The new object will be constructed based on the boolean properties(if these boolean is equal to true). The new array will look like this

```
acl:[
{
view:[
   {username:"Mike", userId:1},
   {username:"Joe", userId:2},
   {username:"Lim", userId:3}
]
update:[
   {username:"Mike", userId:1},
   {username:"Joe", userId:2}
]
remove:[
   {username:"Mike", userId:1}
]
```

Im stuck on constructing the logic inside the iteration. Maybe someone could give me a hint on this.

Comment: This is not a place where the community does your work for you, please show what you have done and where you need assistance.  There is no code in the question above, only a problem as one might see in a homework assignment.  For a very simple exercise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group into an object of arrays:

```js
const acl=[{view:!0,update:!0,remove:!0,userId:1,username:"Mike"},{view:!0,update:!0,remove:!1,userId:2,username:"Joe"},{view:!0,update:!1,remove:!1,userId:3,username:"Lim"}];

console.log(
  acl.reduce((a, { view, update, remove, userId, username }) => {
    const obj = { username, userId };
    if (view) a.view.push(obj);
    if (update) a.update.push(obj);
    if (remove) a.remove.push(obj);
    return a;
  }, { view: [], update: [], remove: [] })
);
```

Or, if the username / userId objects need to be separate references, you can use spread:

```js
const acl=[{view:!0,update:!0,remove:!0,userId:1,username:"Mike"},{view:!0,update:!0,remove:!1,userId:2,username:"Joe"},{view:!0,update:!1,remove:!1,userId:3,username:"Lim"}];

console.log(
  acl.reduce((a, { view, update, remove, userId, username }) => {
    const obj = { username, userId };
    if (view) a.view.push({...obj});
    if (update) a.update.push({...obj});
    if (remove) a.remove.push({...obj});
    return a;
  }, { view: [], update: [], remove: [] })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn't answer this but the number of people telling you to use reduce is killing me.

The neatest way to do this (if you're only working with view/update/remove) would be to use filters. They actually describe the action you're trying to take.

```
const acl2 = {
  view: acl.filter(({view}) => view),
  update: acl.filter(({update}) => update),
  remove: acl.filter(({remove}) => remove),
};
```

Comment: What exactly about `reduce` is it that's killing you? The fact that it only requires the entire list to be iterated once instead of 3 times as per your solution?

Comment: Reduce is quicker to execute. Filter is quicker to comprehend. None of these answers are benefiting the OP on how to use the community appropriately.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen If speed was a concern you would use a for loop. You would never refactor code to a reduce for speed benefits. Both solutions are O(n).

Comment: @david I agree with using a `for` loop for optimal performance. I would indeed not refactor code to use `reduce()` for speed benefits, but I would also not write code that loops an array three times if it can be done in one. Both solutions are indeed linear in complexity, but the difference between O(n) and O(3n) can be significant in some cases.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if the difference between n and 3n was significant then the difference between using reduce and a for loop would be even more so. The difference in readability between reduce and filter is massive. Compare it to using a chain of the methods, say `x.map().filter().map()`, you wouldn't prefer a reduce over that would you?

Answer (score 0):

```
const acl = [{"view":true,"update":true,"remove":true,"userId":1,"username":"Mike"},{"view":true,"update":true,"remove":false,"userId":2,"username":"Joe"},{"view":true,"update":false,"remove":false,"userId":3,"username":"Lim"}]

function multi_dim (array) {

  const res = {
    view: [],
    update: [],
    remove: []
  }

  const keys = Object.keys(array[0])

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
      if (key !== 'username' && key !== 'userId') {
        if (array[i][key]) {
          res[key].push({
            username: array[i].username,
            userId: array[i].userId
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }

  return res

}

let obj = multi_dim(acl) // returns object. Push to array if so desired

console.log(obj)

// => result
//   {
//     "view": [
//       {
//         "username": "Mike",
//         "userId": 1
//       },
//       {
//         "username": "Joe",
//         "userId": 2
//       },
//       {
//         "username": "Lim",
//         "userId": 3
//       }
//     ],
//     "update": [
//       {
//         "username": "Mike",
//         "userId": 1
//       },
//       {
//         "username": "Joe",
//         "userId": 2
//       }
//     ],
//     "remove": [
//       {
//         "username": "Mike",
//         "userId": 1
//       }
//     ]
//   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```
const permissions = ['view', 'update', 'remove'];
const output = acl.reduce((a, v) => {
  permissions.forEach(p => {
    if (v[p]) a[p].push({username: v.username, userId: v.userId});
  });

  return a;
}, permissions.reduce((a, p) => ({ ...a, [p]: []}), {}));
```

```js
const acl = [{
    view: true,
    update: true,
    remove: true,
    userId: 1,
    username: "Mike"
  },
  {
    view: true,
    update: true,
    remove: false,
    userId: 2,
    username: "Joe"
  },
  {
    view: true,
    update: false,
    remove: false,
    userId: 3,
    username: "Lim"
  }];

const permissions = ['view', 'update', 'remove'];

const output = acl.reduce((a, v) => {
  permissions.forEach(p => {
    if (v[p]) a[p].push({username: v.username, userId: v.userId});
  });
  
  return a;
}, permissions.reduce((a, p) => ({ ...a, [p]: []}), {}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @vol7ron *["And little makes me sadder than comments on answers saying, “Don’t answer questions like this – it encourages them."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)*

Comment: Yes, and you obviously know the ins-and-outs and how you should help the OP. I downvoted and I gave you my reason despite not having to because I believe it’s more beneficial.  I don’t believe tolerating every post because it is “welcoming” is going to solve any problem of the OP learning how they should act. The blog entry has its own inherent issues.