# Map keys and create a new object

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "145.10880940000004,-37.9333893,10"
var view = str.split(",");
console.log(view);
```

Creates an array:

```
[
  "145.10880940000004",
  "-37.9333893",
  "10"
]
```

How do I dynamically map the keys so I have an object like this:

```
{
  Lng: "145.10880940000004",
  Lat: "-37.9333893",
  Zoom: "10"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work, using array destructuring:

```js
const input = "145.10880940000004,-37.9333893,10";
const [Lng, Lat, Zoom] = input.split(',');
const output = {Lng, Lat, Zoom};

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @Robby Looks like this isn't supported in quite a few browsers though.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah well, I know how to use a for loop, I was looking for a modern and elegant approach.

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, I helped a newbie out in the same way two days ago in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790605/create-new-multidimensional-array-based-on-this-existing-array-objec/50790662#50790662) and got the same reaction with some more downvotes. Ever since that [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) about being more welcoming on SO got published it feels like things have gotten even worse. I'm just trying to help some people out, in this case a fellow user who has already earned their stripes.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...input.split(',').map((v,i)=>({[['Lng', 'Lat', 'Zoom'][i]]:v})))` if you want to only "write" the property names once :p

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Robby Cornelissen's answer, if you have multiple of these values, you can do this neatly with `.map` and parameter destructuring:

```js
const values = [
  "145.10880940000004,-37.9333893,10",
  "145.10880940000004,-37.9333893,10",
];

console.log(
  values
    .map(str => str.split(','))
    .map(([Lng, Lat, Zoom]) => ({Lng, Lat, Zoom}))
);
```

Comment: Read his comment though *very old and very insecure* browser. :)

Comment: Cool. Hadn't even thought of throwing parameter destructuring into the mix.

Comment: @JaromandaX That answer would maybe not have been deleted if you had not downvoted it.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...input.split(',').map((v,i)=>({[['Lng', 'Lat', 'Zoom'][i]]:v})))`

Comment: meh ... it's more complex than it needs to be, you could split it up a bit, but still only need to have `Lat Lng Zoom` in the code once :p So if in the future you add a 4th property, you add it in one place only